# compare absolute value with double value present in table using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, compare, absolute-value

select id from records where (mean_logratio = -4.81)

-4.810215473175049 value is present in the table which supposed to be fetched

-4.810215473175049 only exact value is accepted not absolute value, in search query for = and != condition

for absolute value like -4.81, not getting expected results

Answer (score 0):

You can go with either approach:

1. If you want to compare after rounding off upto two decimal place.

```
select distinct(workflowid) 
from cyto_records r join cyto_record_results rr on (r.recordid = rr.recordid) 
where (round(rr.mean_logratio::numeric,2) = -4.81)
```

2. If you want to truncate upto two decimal and compare then use below mentioned query:

```
select distinct(workflowid) 
from cyto_records r join cyto_record_results rr on (r.recordid = rr.recordid)
where (trunc(rr.mean_logratio::numeric,2) = -4.81)
```

In case of data type mismatch error, you may need to cast you data.

Comment: ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 3: where (round(rr.mean_logratio,2) = -4.81)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 116

Comment: ERROR:  function trunc(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 3: where (trunc(rr.mean_logratio,2) = -4.81)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 115

Comment: I'm using Postgresql

Comment: I have clearly mention in the last that you may have to cast your data. you need to cast your rr.mean_logratio to numeric or decimal. Please try the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much I got the expected result

Comment: You are welcome. Its good practice on SO to accept the answer if it resolve your problem and upvote also